# kinect 3D data coordinates

Tags: ros, kinect, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Question. pleaes tell me the answer~

kinect 3D data has the X,Y,Z coordinates.

Where is the X,Y,Z data's (0,0,0)?

kinect sensor? kinect lens?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41257/kinect-3d-data-coordinates/) by [ha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2979/ha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is somewhere in the lens. I'd recommend transforming the data to some better usable frame like the kinect link.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-08-13**:
Sorry. I don't understand your mean. Can you expain again?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-14**:
The origin should be somewhere near the lens or actually in the camera. Usually you want distances  relative to something you, so I'd recommend using a frame like the kinect's base frame. It depends on what you want to do with the data.